# Use a template event to trigger a response in another template

Tags: javascript, meteor

When an event happens in a template, I want to do something in another template.

this is my code:

client html:

> ```
>     <body>
>       Navigation:
>       {{> navigation}}
>       =======================================================
>       Body:
>       {{> body}}
>     </body>
>
>
>      <template name="navigation">
>       <input type="button" value="MenuBtn" />
>     </template>
>     <template name="body">
>      {{content}}
>     </template>
> ```

JavaScript:

```
    Template.navigation.events({
        'click' : function (e) {    

            //Nothing happened in {{body}}
            Template.body.content = function(){
             // i want to do something... like query database
             // maybe, just a example : return peple.find({"name":e.currenTarget.value});                   
              return "hello";       
            };          

        } });
```

Any idea about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use handlebars to pass data to the template so the templating system knows when to redraw the html

Client JS

```
Template.body.content = function() {
    return Session.get("content") || "Hi there, click the button" 
};

Template.navigation.events({
    'click' : function () {     
        alert("1");// it's normal       
        Session.set("content", "<h1>HELLO!!!! '+ people.findOne({"name":e.currenTarget.value}).name || " unregisterd person" + '</h1>");         
        alert("2");//it's normal
    }
});
```

I also assume you're going to do something HTMLey and you don't want it to be escaped so make sure you use:

```
<template name="body">
    {{{content}}}
</template>
```

Comment: It's very perfect.I'm very grateful for you. but are there any other  way without session? I worry will be a lot of data in the session...

Comment: Session isn't really a 'cookie' or anything per say its more just a hashmap, it should be fine with lots of data too. If you have alot of data use another template and use more handlebar helpers to fill it up, instead of `{{content}}` use {{date}} e.g for the date and each individual variable. If you want to use it for content use a router such as Meteor Router